# Is Huawei HG8245H configurable as a client?

Tags: router, lan

I have two routers. The first (D-Link) is connected to the internet and it has 4 Lan Ports. Can i connect the second one (Huawei HG8245H) to a LAN port of the D-Link router? I mean, i want to use  Huawei HG8245H as a device connected in the local area of the D-Link router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled the Huawei's DHCP server and configured it's IP to one from the D-Link's local area and it worked.